# target html on specific page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying something i would've thought to be quite simple but has turned out to be much more difficult than i thought. I'm simply trying to apply the following css to a specific page, but i see no way of targeting the html for a specific page without affecting the entire site.

CSS

`html {overflow-y: hidden;}`

I'm using wordpress and i've found no way to add a class (or an ID) to the html of the page.

Can anyone help me with a solution to my problem?

Thanks

Comment: I' don't think that you can make that possible with css. Try writing a javascript solution that will check if window.location is matching the desired page - and if so - change the css.

Comment: @Jakob-Natorp Please add more details to your question. Which page are you referring to? Is it a generic worddpress template page or a custom page? Elaborate more on your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following PHP into your `functions.php` file to add the URL of your page in the body class. Then you can use `body.page-xxxxx` to target specific pages or posts with CSS.

```html
<?php
//Page Slug Body Class
function add_slug_body_class( $classes ) {
global $post;
if ( isset( $post ) ) {
$classes[] = $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name;
}
return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_slug_body_class' );
?>
```